# C# using, how many variables it will dispose in a chained instantiation/method calls

Tags: c#, .net, idisposable

No similar questions came up after a quick search, hence asking this question.
Just wondering which of the dispose methods will be called and in what order?

```
using(var bar = new FooDisposable().Bar())
{
    //Will this using call both (IFooDisposable.Dispose and IBarDisposable.Dispose) the dispose methods?
}

public class FooDisposable : IFooDisposable 
{
    public IBarDisposable Bar()
    {
        return new ImplOfIBarDisposable();
    }
}

public interface IFooDisposable : IDisposable
{
    IBarDisposable Bar();
}

public interface IBarDisposable : IDisposable
{   
}
```

Comment: No, it will be called only on the return value of `Bar()`

Comment: All you had to do was run the code to find out what happened and when.

Comment: @Servy, I like your answering attitude. I could have done the testing myself, but intention was to bring the side effect to attention because most of the time we chain the calls for brevity.

Comment: @NasmiSabeer did you miss my answer to your question? Is my answer missing something that you require?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only `IBarDisposable` will have its `Dispose()` called.

[This MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) is quite helpful.

```
using (Font font1 = new Font("Arial", 10.0f)) 
{
    byte charset = font1.GdiCharSet;
}
```

becomes

```
{
  Font font1 = new Font("Arial", 10.0f);
  try
  {
    byte charset = font1.GdiCharSet;
  }
  finally
  {
    if (font1 != null)
      ((IDisposable)font1).Dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: `Only IBarDisposable will have its Dispose() called`. it is not fully correct. Only `IDisposable` will have its Dispose() called. IDisposable.Dispose can be implemeted explicitly: https://dotnetfiddle.net/yhitw1

Comment: @ASh Actually yes my statement is fully correct in the context of his question. His `IBarDisposable` does not include an explicit implementation for `Dispose()`  You are certainly correct that, if he had, it would be an important distinction. I'm sure a future reader will be helped by your example, though.